# iptables firewall whitelisting limit

Tags: security, firewall, iptables

We have a distributed system with many clients connecting to this system.

We want the server to be isolated so that only client machines can connect.

We are using IPTables as follow:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s Client1 -p tcp --dport <server_port> -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s Client2 -p tcp --dport <server_port> -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport <server_port> -j DROP
```

The clients machine could be in 1000s. Will the iptables be able to handle these many machines?

Are there any limit on number of client machines listed in iptables?

Will be there any performance impact if we add 800+ client machines?

Will there be any impact on security (we want to isolate server-client from any non recognized machine)?

Answer (score 1):

Use **ipset**

It will be far easier to manage and have better performance.

I have block list of over 1 million and it has a negligible impact.  Below comments and counters are optional, but nice to have.

```
ipset create whitelist hash:net counters comment maxelem 1000000

iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set --match-set whitelist src -j ACCEPT
```

This way your iptables isn't clutter with basically identical rules.  In addition to speed, it just makes your iptables 1000 times easier to troubleshoot.

You will have to save and restore your rules.

```
ipset save >ipset.txt
ipset restore <ipset.txt
```

FYI:

ipset whitelist add 192.168.0.0/16 comment "client 1"